# PowerApps question regarding If statements and ThisItem not displaying value at all

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm having a PowerApps issue.

I'm trying to write an If statement. Currently, Overdue_Days = 260 and it's in DataCardValue27 as a Number. However, the formula is not displaying the number 4 as it should. Any advice?

This formula is being input in the Default section.

Below is the formula I am trying:

If(
IsBlank(ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:'),
"",
If(
And(
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' >= 0.0001,
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' <= 83.9950
),
1,
If(
And(
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' >= 83.9960,
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' <= 119.9980
),
2,
If(
And(
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' >= 119.9990,
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' <= 174.9950
),
3,
If(
And(
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' >= 174.9960,
ThisItem.'Overdue_Days:' <= 99999.0000
),
4,
""
)
)
)
)
)

Comment: I figured out what was happening. It seems I have to submit the form 3 times for the formulas to all perform. Is there a way to make them calculate automatically without having to hit the submit button 3 times?

Comment: Or is there a way for it to submit the form 3 times in a row so the calculations can take affect?

Comment: Basically, I have one if statement that does a calculation. Then another if statement that needs that value to make a calculation. Then another if statement that uses that value. So, it takes me 3 submits to get it all into the SharePoint list. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Having to submit the form 3 times does not feel like the right explanation to your issue. Have you tried to use the Monitor functionality to analyze what goes wrong with the first 2 submissions? Also, your formula is a bit overcomplicated. You could achieve the same effect with less code if you add the conditions in reverse order, like if a>99999,4,a>174,3 and so on. The If(Isblank()) part can also be simplified with the Coalesce() function.

Comment: Thanks. I did simplify the formula. I was wondering if I may need to do something with OnChange to make the fomulas work when the date value changes.

Comment: Since you use ThisItem, the formula is inside a Gallery I guess? Regardless what your datasource is, you have to patch it first. ThisItem is pointing to a record inside the source, changing any control that has OnChange will have no direct effect on ThisItem. You could also add more details and/or screenshots to your question to make your scenario clearer

Comment: Not inside of a Gallery. It's on the Edit Screen.

Comment: I'm a noob. First time trying this.

Comment: Hang in there :) do you have a screenshot of the screen you made. It would help us understand what is going on.